# How to create trigger prevent update if the value of foreign key not correct - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm working in a java project using hibernate, when I select data from one table I got the following error  : `ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found` when I made some analysis I found that hibernate make update before each select, and this update cause the problem because the foreign key in this update is not found in the parent table.

I can't make the correction in the app, so my idea is to make a trigger before update each row to prevent the update if the value of the foreign key is not exists in the parent table.

I'm using Oracle.

This is my code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_prevent_update
BEFORE UPDATE  ON my_table FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN


--I'm not sure if this if will works
if :new.column_fk not in(select pk from parent_table) then

--do something to prevent update whithout generation exception to keep the app working

end if;


END;
```

Can anyone guide me to achieve my correction.

Regards!

Comment: Why do you need foreign key in this case?

Comment: Hi, i didn't understand your question, can you please explain to me what you mean ?

Comment: If your application changes value of foreign key in child_table and this value does not exist in parent_table, maybe you need delete foreign key or insert entry with new value into parent_table before update child_table.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's what FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT is for: it prevents you from entering invalid values. So, why would you want to prevent that? A trigger you dream of, that would automagically "fix" your problem, would fire **always**, not only from your Java application. Barbaros suggested RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR which isn't an improvement (at least, I think so). If you don't want to *raise* an error, you can ignore it (for example, do NULL). But that makes foreign key constraint useless. In my opinion, you should fix the root cause, i.e. that *untouchable* application of yours.

Comment: @Littlefoot thank you for your time, i fix the problem by desabling the constraint, it 's not the perfect solution but this is what i can do in my level ,Regards !

Comment: I'm afraid that you made the problem **way bigger**, but hey - that's your database, do with it what you find the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Purpose of this "answer" is to demonstrate that:

1. trigger Barbaros suggested is useless, as foreign key constraint does that job itself.
2. disabling the foreign key constraint Ali performed is a big, HUGE no-no

I'm creating two "classic" master-detail tables, DEPT and EMP, where EMP.DEPTNO has a foreign key constraint pointing to DEPT.DEPTNO. Then, there's a trigger (more or less copy/paste of Barbaros' code).

```
SQL> create table dept
  2    (deptno  number   constraint pk_dept primary key,
  3     dname   varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table emp
  2    (empno   number   constraint pk_emp primary key,
  3     ename   varchar2(20),
  4     deptno  number   constraint fk_emp_dept references dept (deptno));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_prevent_update
  2    before insert or update on emp
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    v_cnt int;
  6  begin
  7    select count(*) into v_cnt
  8      from dept t
  9      where t.deptno = :new.deptno;
 10
 11    if v_cnt = 0 then
 12       raise_application_error(-20101, 'My own trigger prevents insert or update');
 13    end if;
 14  end;
 15  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Now, testing.

```
SQL> -- Insert some valid data
SQL> insert into dept (deptno, dname) values (10, 'Accounting');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into emp (empno, ename, deptno) values (1, 'LF', 10);

1 row created.
```

> 1. Barbaros' suggestion:

```
SQL> -- Update EMP.DEPTNO to a non-existent value
SQL> update emp set deptno = 20;
update emp set deptno = 20
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20101: My own trigger prevents insert or update
ORA-06512: at "HR.TRG_PREVENT_UPDATE", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.TRG_PREVENT_UPDATE'


SQL>
```

OK, trigger prevented me to update EMP.DEPTNO to an invalid value. I'll now disable that trigger and repeat the same UPDATE statement.

```
SQL> -- Disable trigger
SQL> alter trigger trg_prevent_update disable;

Trigger altered.

SQL> -- Update EMP.DEPTNO to a non-existent value, again
SQL> update emp set deptno = 20;
update emp set deptno = 20
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HR.FK_EMP_DEPT) violated - parent key not
found


SQL>
```

See? UPDATE failed due to foreign key constraint violation. So, what's the purpose of creating a trigger? It doesn't *solve* nor add anything.

> 2. Ali's disabled foreign key constraint

```
SQL> -- Disable the constraint
SQL> alter table emp disable constraint fk_emp_dept;

Table altered.

SQL> update emp set deptno = 20;

1 row updated.

SQL> insert into emp (empno, ename, deptno) values (2, 'Mickey', 666);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME
---------- --------------------
        10 Accounting

SQL> select * From emp;

     EMPNO ENAME                    DEPTNO
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 LF                           20
         2 Mickey                      666

SQL>
```

Now that's beautiful! Both UPDATE and INSERT went well, and now you have inconsistent data all over your tables.

> Just to repeat myself:

You (Ali) should fix the issue in Java application which performs unnecessary INSERT that fails, and yes - it fails for a reason. Don't disable the constraint. You might deeply regret it, sooner than later.

Comment: ok, you mean to solve problem in the application layer rather than in the db, you're right.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Database does its job correctly, preventing users from inserting/updating invalid values. It is the application that produces mess, and it should be fixed.

Comment: @Littlefoot thank you so much , you are the man, yes you are right but i desable the constraint because i was in cretical situtation in prouction mode, even if i correc the problem in the java application , i can't make a deployment also the problem is related to hibernate itselef for some object he made a update before insert.

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to warn you, but - as I've already said - it is your database, do whatever you find appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

To Perform prevention, you can use this trigger body :

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trg_prevent_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
     v_cnt int;
BEGIN
     select count(1) into v_cnt from parent_table t where t.code = :new.column_fk;   
  if ( v_cnt = 0 ) then
     raise_application_error(-20101,'the foreign key does not exist in the parent table!'); 
  end if;  
END;
```

to warn you about problem before update, and prevents update operation.

Comment: hi @Barbaros, thanks for your rsponse, do you think that raise_application_error will not generat exception in my application ?

Comment: @Ali you're welcome. Exception will occur , if you have a problematic record with respect to your foreign key constraint, and application will stop in that case.

Comment: Barbaros, I don't understand what improvement that brings. If you do absolutely nothing (current situation), ORA-02291 is raised. If you use RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR, ORA-20101 is raised, only with a different message.

Comment: @Littlefoot ok, i should elaborate, i've edited due to OP wants to prevent the update if the value of the foreign key is not exists in the parent table.

Comment: I still think that a trigger solves *nothing*. Please, have a look at demonstration I posted. If I got you wrong, do create a full example yourself, I'll be glad to review it.

Comment: @Littlefoot Dear fellow your demonstration is good, and i already understand what you mean to me, when you have commented :) if you issue this statement `update emp set deptno = 10;`, you'll be successful but for other values fail and raise problem in such cases, and as far as understand the problem of Ali is to distinguish between these cases.

Comment: I'm following you to "as far as understand the problem" :) Distinguish between *which* cases? It seems that I just can't figure out what you are pointing to (I must be quite stupid nowadays, I'm afraid).

Comment: @Littlefoot oh,no, you're such precious software specialist.

Comment: Ah, thank you, feeling much better now :) Though, I'd rather understand what you were saying.